# How frequency generated on water can affect it's flow on camera?

Tags: experimental-physics

I have a science fair project, and it can be summed up in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mODqQvlrgIQ).

The problem is that only a sub woofer can generate a pure 23.24 Hz frequency and I can't afford a sub woofer. So I was wondering, if I adjust the frame of the camera to 50 frames, and produce a 50-60 Hz frequency from an amplifier, will it have the same effect on the water as shown in the video?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 50Hz should have a similar effect. When you do the experiment please post a link to the video here!

The problem with increasing the frequency is that the water has less time to respond to the pressure changes, because they occur faster. This means the effect of the sound will be smaller and you'll need a higher amplitude, i.e. louder sound, to have the same effect. I don't know whether this will be a problem when doubling the frequency to 50Hz, and I suspect this would be hard to predict. The best option is to try it and see.